# TASKKILL command works properly outside Script, but not inside of it

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-3.0, taskkill

Few days ago I started developing a Powershell script which monitors a service. Command:

```
taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq admin" /im tm1top.exe
```

When I ran `taskkill` to stop one process inside my script it didn’t work: that process remained in Running, hence the script was not able to end properly.

On the other hand, running exactly the same command (`taskkill`) from CMD directly was successful.

NOTE: the user which is running this script has ADMIN RIGHTS on the computer and I am running Windows Seever 2008. Also tried to create a task into Windows Scheduler and to run it with highest privileges with this user, but the same result..

Could you please advise what should I modify in order to make this function work directly from my ps script?

Comment: I suggest learning powershell and looking at the documentation for `Stop-Process`.

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 I have tried using Stop-Process, but it doesn’t help me because you cannot kill a process for a specific user with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using WMI for this:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Where-Object {
    $_.GetOwner().User -eq 'admin' -and
    $_.Name -eq 'tm1top.exe'
} | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Terminate()
}
```

Comment: `$_.GetOwner().Name` doesn't work for me. For me `$_.GetOwner().User` does work.

Comment: @Theo Indeed. I got distracted when typing the sample code. Sorry.